# Can't get the information for the current user

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

As you can see in the following code, after successfully logging in, it should print the user information containing the user, admin comment, and the start/expiring date from the credentials data-frame, on the first page. However, it does not show up. What could be the problem? grateful for guidance.

```
# define some credentials
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("11", "1", "1", "1"), # mandatory
  password = c("1", "1", "1", "1"), # mandatory
  start = c("2022-02-14"), # optinal (all others)
  expire = c(NA, "2019-12-31"),
  admin = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
  comment = "Welcom to the Shiny applications.",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

ui<-fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
  "Shiny",
  tabPanel(
    "Information"),
  tags$h2("Information about the current user"),
  verbatimTextOutput("auth_output")
  
  
  
  )
)



# Wrap your UI with secure_app
ui <- secure_app(ui)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # call the server part
  # check_credentials returns a function to authenticate users
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  
  output$auth_output <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
  })
  
  # your classic server logic
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a panel such as `mainPanel` in your `navbarPage`:

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    "Shiny",
    tabPanel(
      "Information"),
    tags$h2("Information about the current user"),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("auth_output")
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi sir @PorkChop maybe with your shiny expertise could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268220/how-to-include-showmodal-and-modaldialog-like-popup-when-using-multiple-tabpan many thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bad, fixed it, rookie mistake, thanks.

```
# define some credentials
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("11", "1", "1", "1"), # mandatory
  password = c("1", "1", "1", "1"), # mandatory
  start = c("2022-02-14"), # optinal (all others)
  expire = c(NA, "2019-12-31"),
  admin = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
  comment = "Welcom to the Shiny applications.",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

ui<-fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
  "Shiny",
  tabPanel(
    "Information",
    tags$h2("Information about the current user"),
    verbatimTextOutput("auth_output")
    
    ),
  tabPanel("Simulation"),
  tabPanel("Simulation"),
  tabPanel("Simulation"),
  tabPanel("Simulation")
  
  
  
  )
)



# Wrap your UI with secure_app
ui <- secure_app(ui)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # call the server part
  # check_credentials returns a function to authenticate users
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  
  output$auth_output <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
  })
  
  # your classic server logic
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Enrique, welcome to the Stack. Do take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't done so already. Can you explain how this has solved your original problem? Is this answer direct response to @Pork Chop's answer? If he has answered your question then you should accept his answer. Answers should be self-contained, so please use comments to respond to other user's answers.