# How to include showModal and modalDialog (like popup) when using multiple tabPanel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am working to create a shiny that consists of multiple tabs and inside each tab a form below `shinysurveys` can be filled. The code for the design of the app works showing the tabs and its content.

In order to make more informative the app, I would like to include a message that appears every time the Tab1 is clicked and also as Tab1 is placed in first position, it should appear when the app is opened or loaded. In order to reach that goal I used a combination of `modalDialog()` and `showModal()` inside `server` but it is not working. The code for my app is next:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinysurveys)
#Questions 1
df1 <- data.frame(question = "What is your favorite food?",
                 option = "Your Answer",
                 input_type = "text",
                 input_id = "favorite_food",
                 dependence = NA,
                 dependence_value = NA,
                 required = F)
#Questions 2
df2 <- data.frame(question = "Where do you live?",
                 option = "Your Answer",
                 input_type = "text",
                 input_id = "city",
                 dependence = NA,
                 dependence_value = NA,
                 required = F)
#App
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(id = "AC",
              tabPanel(tabName = "A1","Tab1",
                       surveyOutput(df = df1,theme='pink',
                                    survey_title = "Hello",
                                    survey_description = "This is page 1.")),
              tabPanel(tabName = "A2","Tab2",
                       surveyOutput(df = df2,theme='pink',
                                    survey_title = "Hello",
                                    survey_description = "This is page 2."))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$AC,{ 
    if(input$AC == "A1")
    {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Hello again!",
        "You are in page 1!",
        easyClose = TRUE
      ))
    } else{}
  }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The code works fine but it is not displaying the message I would like to get for the first Tab. In order to show a message for the first tab, I have used `observeEvent()` and created a condition for the id of `tabsetPanel()` when `tabPanel()` takes the value of A1 using `showModal()` and `modalDialog()` but when I run the app I did not get the message. I only get this, without the message:

[image]

I do not know if something is wrong with code. In the end I would like to replicate the same funcionality (without the styling showed) in this app: [Link for the app](https://dgranjon.shinyapps.io/bs4DashDemo/)

You can see that when the app starts a message is showed because the first tab (Basic cards) is showed. And every time you go to that tab, the message is showed.

Many thanks for your help.